# cloudwatch alarm in boto3 gives error in unit

Tags: boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to learn cloudwatch alarms on boto3 ,amazon ec2 instances how they can be programmed in custom scripts.

```
import boto3
import time
# Create CloudWatch client
cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

# Create alarm with actions enabled
cloudwatch.put_metric_alarm(
    AlarmName='Web_Server_CPU_Utilization',
    ComparisonOperator='GreaterThanThreshold',
    EvaluationPeriods=1,
    MetricName='CPUUtilization',
    Namespace='AWS/EC2',
    Period=60,
    Statistic='Average',
    Threshold=70.0,
    ActionsEnabled=True,
    AlarmActions=[
      'arn:aws:swf:us-west-2:{CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT}:action/actions/AWS_EC2.InstanceId.Reboot/1.0'
    ],
    AlarmDescription='Alarm when server CPU exceeds 70%',
    Dimensions=[
        {
          'Name': 'InstanceId',
          'Value': 'INSTANCE_ID'
        },
    ],
    Unit='Seconds'
)
```

However upon execution of above program I am getting error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\expt2\cloudwatch alarm in action.py", line 27, in <module>
    Unit='Seconds'
  File "E:\installation2\python3\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 314, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "E:\installation2\python3\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 612, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the PutMetricAlarm operation: Unknown
```

This sample code which is giving me error ,how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ValidationError` is documented (a little bit) [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/CommonErrors.html).

The error is being caused by the badly-formatted item in the list of `AlarmActions`. That should be formatted like:

> arn:aws:swf:*region*:*account-id*:action/actions/AWS_EC2.InstanceId.Reboot/1.0

Meanwhile you have

> arn:aws:swf:us-west-2:{CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT}:action/actions/AWS_EC2.InstanceId.Reboot/1.0

So you just need to update to use a real AWS Account ID where you have `{CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT}`.

Comment: oh should I put my loginid in the {CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT} field

Comment: Your account ID see here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/console_account-alias.html